# Validating number precision/scale

Tags: php, oracle, validation, scale, precision

How would I validate the precision/scale of a number posted from a form to make sure it can be stored in an Oracle NUMBER column?  For example:

```
<input type="number" name="foo" value="123.45" />
```

The user submits the form to the PHP backend...

```
<?php
function isValidNumber($number, $precision, $scale) {
    // ???

    return $isValid;
}

// The precision and scale here are actually dynamic
$isValid = isValidNumber($_POST['foo'], 5, 2);
```

...where I would like to be able to validate the number without trying to insert/update it in Oracle and handle any precision overflow errors (proactive design, rather than reactive).  I have not been able to come up with a method of accurately validating all the various fringe cases (Oracle doesn't produce errors for scale overflow - it just rounds to the maximum, but this rounding could lead to precision overflows, which do produce errors, etc.).

Comment: What library are you using to interface with your Oracle database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
function isValidNumber($number, $precision, $scale) {
    $isValid = false;
    if (is_numeric($number)) {
        $num = round(abs($number), $scale);
        $max = str_repeat('9',$precision - $scale).'.'.str_repeat('9',$scale);
        $isValid = $num <= $max;
    }
    return $isValid;
}
```

Output for `isValidNumber($number, 5, 2)`

```
123.456   (valid)
9999.999  (invalid)
99999.999 (invalid)
12.003    (valid)
999.99    (valid)
999.999   (invalid)
1234.5    (invalid)
```

and finally

`isValid(1234567890123456789012345678.90, 30, 2) == **valid**`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this function fails for valid Oracle input.  For example, "123.456" is valid input for a NUMBER(5, 2) column.  Oracle will simply round it and store it as "123.46".

Comment: Didn't you say you wanted to prevent Oracle from rounding it?

Comment: Nope, I just want to make sure whatever number I give Oracle won't produce an overflow error.  This function would do that, but it would also prevent values that Oracle wouldn't produce an error for.

Comment: Okay, I changed line 4 in the code above. See if that helps. :)

Comment: It is better, but still fails for cases when the scale rounding produces a precision error.  For example, isValidNumber("999.999", 5, 2) should return false, but your version returns true.  It should return false because Oracle rounds 999.999 to 1000.00, because the scale is 2.  1000.00 has a precision of 6, so it produces an overflow error.

Comment: I see. Try it now. I think we've just about got it.

Comment: isValidNumber("1234.5", 5, 2) is returning true, but should be false.Also, isValidNumber("1234567890123456789012345678.90", 30, 2) is returning false, but should be returning true.

Comment: How is 1234.5 invalid when 5 is the precision (number of digits) and 2 is the scale (number of digits to the right of the decimal)? That makes no sense. It's perfectly valid. As for the second number, PHP can't handle a number that large without introducing its own rounding errors. (It converts it to 1.2345678901235E+27)

Comment: I've gone beyond answering a question. This is free work. I suggest you hire someone to look into this for you. But, I'd really like to know why you think isValidNumber("1234.5", 5, 2) should be false. That baffles me.

Comment: The scale is 2, so 1234.5 is actually 1234.50, which is precision 6,  not 5.  The maximum value that Oracle can store in a NUMBER(5, 2) column is 999.99, because it reserves 2 significant digits after the decimal, meaning a maximum of 3 can come before it.  Since 1234.5 has 4 digits before the decimal (or 1234.5 > 999.99), a precision overflow error is produced - and that's what I'm trying to prevent.  I appreciate your help, and I hope you don't think I'm ungrateful, but I'm unfortunately not in a position to accept a solution that does not work in all cases.

Comment: I completely rewrote the code. It works for the test cases we've discussed so far. Unfortunately, I can't prove it will work for _all_ cases.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, since it's an intriguing method I had never thought about using and works in all practical cases.  It will still fail during scale overflow for very large numbers (ex. isValidNumber(9999999999999999999999999999.999, 30, 2) - if you're curious), but I don't use columns with large enough precisions for this to be an issue.  Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: In such extreme cases, it's probably better to let Oracle issue an error anyway. Nevertheless, feel free to tweak the code to whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using n number of ways. Following can be starting point

- Client Side validation using HTML5 validation

A suggested way can be using Regex pattern based matches using HTML5 only.

```
input type="text" pattern="regex"
```

Disclaimer : the pattern logic has not been tested, so you will have to test it before you use anywhere

```
-?([0-9]{0,precision-scale}\.[0-9]{1,scale}|[0-9]{1,precision-scale})
```

the same Regex logic can also be used at any of the following layers which have there own plus and minus

- Client Side using Java-script Validation
- Server Side using php validation
- Validation at DB layer and throwing error all across different
  layers

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not address scale rounding.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get this... Oracle rounds off if the number is not in configured scale value and you wanted to handle this in your UI layer. The Regex pattern will match and you can throw a validation warning for unmatched patterns. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The regex pattern you have given matches "999999999999.999999999999" and other invalid data which would cause database errors.

Comment: Thank you, but the new regex is also still matching "999999999999.999999999999" and other invalid data.

Comment: Client side validation is unreliable. Always validate on the server side.

Comment: @NUllUserException , I did mentioned there is plus and minus of validation at different layers

Comment: @drrcknlsn Can you please show what precision and scale you are using with test data and expected output.

Answer (score -1):

Get the length of the string , get the position of the decimal
this will give you the total decimal places

```
$len = strlen($num); 
$p = strpos($num, '.'); 
$dec_plcs = ($len - $p) - 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but this does not validate precision or scale.  Numbers with more than <scale> decimal places can still be valid.

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought you need to validate a certain amount of decimal places. Would you explain it to me a little more, and I'll help you look for an answer.

Comment: I'm looking for a function written in PHP that will tell me whether or not Oracle is going to allow me to store a given number in a column, based on its precision and scale.

Comment: If your concerned about Oracle changing the value, maybe a solution would be to store it as a string. Do you need to do processing on it as a number at the DB level or is that a possibility?

Comment: I simply want to ensure that my form input does not produce Oracle precision overflow errors when I use it in inserts/updates.  For example, if $_POST['foo'] is "9999999999999.99999" and I try to insert it into a NUMBER(5,2) column, Oracle will produce a precision overflow error.

Comment: -1 For suggesting the use of string types to store numeric data.